# Exception coming from System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DisconnectEx_Blocking on Socket Disconnect

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, nullreferenceexception

We have a server application that communicates with devices via TCP sockets. Intermittently when it's trying to upload a file to the device it crashes with a NullReferenceException. It seems that there is an unhandled exception in the internal sockets thread pool.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DisconnectEx_Blocking(IntPtr socketHandle, IntPtr overlapped, Int32 flags, Int32 reserved)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Disconnect(Boolean reuseSocket)
   at Disconnect()
```

Does anybody have any idea about this issue? Is it a framework bug?
I have used Visual Studio 2019 and .Net framework 4.8.

Code Sample

```
protected Socket _socket;
_socket = new Socket(_endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
                {
                    Blocking = true, 
                    NoDelay = true
                };
public virtual void Disconnect()
{
    Log.Trace("Attempting to close the socket.");
    _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    _socket.Close();
    Log.Trace("Socket close successful.");
}
```

Comment: The connection closed.  Can't tell why the connection closed from info provided.

Comment: Edited the code